# PyGeocoder with API Key

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I am using PyGeocoder

https://bitbucket.org/xster/pygeocoder/wiki/Home

I have created an API key with the simple server option, this does not present me with a CLIENT_ID option.

So I have the code:

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
business_geocoder = Geocoder(None, 'MY_API_KEY')
address_string = "London, United Kingdom"
results = business_geocoder.geocode(address_string)
```

This works fine, but my quote usage is not being reported in the admin console window, and I can change my API_key to any value and it still works. Is anyone else using this feature and if so how did you implement?

E.g. this code works

```
business_geocoder = Geocoder(client_id=None, private_key='whatever')
```

This code, gives an error:

```
business_geocoder = Geocoder(client_id="some", private_key='whatever')

pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error Forbidden, 403
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=&region=&signature=hrlktNatq4RvlN9Cvd6VNQf8FMw%3D&bounds=&client=some&components=&address=Barnfield+Drive%2C+Chichester%2C+United+Kingdom&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#business-specific_parameters) seems to indicate that the Simple API key authentication method is not supported with Geocoding APIs but they still work somehow.

I just updated version 1.2.3 of [pygeocoder](http://code.xster.net/pygeocoder) so you should be able to just do

```
Geocoder('YOUR_API_KEY').geocode(...
```

after you upgrade your module

```
pip install --upgrade pygeocoder
```